# What is this linq code doing? Summarize something?

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to Linq and c#. Can c# expert explain to me what this code is supposed to do?

```
var sumPoints = (from p in maxPointList
                    orderby p.X
                group p by p.X into q
                select new Point
                {
                    X = q.Key,
                    Y = q.Sum(x => x.Y)
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Order `maxPointList` by `X`, group by `X`, put it into `q` and create new `Point` for each value where `X` is the key of grouped `maxPointList` and `Y` is the sum of values in grouped element?

Comment: For each X gives you the sum of all Y's

Comment: It's sorting a `maxPointList` first by the `X`-value, then it groups by it. These (unique) X values are used to create a new `Point` where the Y value is the sum of all Y values of each X-group. The result is a `List<Point>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to visualize. Say you have points like:

```
X,Y
5, 10
5, 15
6, 4
7, 6
7, 7
4, 2
4, 3
2, 3
```

It is summarizing this as (as an List< Point >) - sorted on X, Y values summed for a given X:

```
2,3
4,5
5, 25
6, 4
7, 13
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes all the entries in maxPointList, sorted by p.X
It then builds a new dictionary, q, where each value of p.X is grouped into a single value in q.
For each of these (having p.X of the same value), it creates a new Point, where Point.X is the p.X value and Point.Y is the total of all of the p.Xs of that value.